# Vector of matches VBA

Tags: vba, loops, vector, match

I am currently looking for the following issue. I would like to find every position of a particular matches and store them into a vector called pos. In my example I would like to know every row in the range(E1:E500) where "SG" appears. Then I would like to loop through this vector.

I have tried the following code but it seems not to work. Can anyone help me?

```
Sub test()
    Set rangenew = Range("E1:E500")

    pos = Application.Match("SG", rangenew, False)

End Sub
```

the results should be something like

```
pos = (1,6,8,10)
```

Then I would like to loop through this vector to test conditions.

Thanks for your great help.

Comment: There are no built-in functions that do this. Write one yourself by checking all rows in a loop and saving the `i` if it contains `"SG"`.

Comment: thanks for your help, I appreciate it

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As @GSerg explained in the comments, there is no built-in function for returning matched row numbers. Something like the below should do what you're after.

```
Public Sub getRows()

    Dim wb As Workbook, ws As Worksheet
    Dim checkData() As Variant, pos() As Long
    Dim i As Long
    Dim matchCount As Long

    Set wb = ThisWorkbook
    Set ws = wb.Sheets(1)

    checkData = ws.Range("E1:E500")

    For i = LBound(checkData, 1) To UBound(checkData, 1)

        If checkData(i, 1) = "SG" Then

            matchCount = matchCount + 1
            ReDim Preserve pos(1 To matchCount)
            pos(matchCount) = i

        End If

    Next i

End Sub
```

Comment: @Iturner Thanks a lot for this nice code and your great explanations. That helps me a lot. Have a nice day :)